# Page rendering differently when default.aspx was modified

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have  code deployed on IIS server, i just tried to modify some html content in Default.aspx page to show site was in "under construction" mode then later i brought back Default.aspx page as it was in original stage (i had copy of original Default.aspx).
I also added app_offline.html file to root directory to bring site to offline, now removed this file from root.
But now when we access the website IIS renders differently and give actual result only after 6-7 refreshes.
I tried to restart IIS server as i read that iis server is rendering new change structure and forgotten old rendering pattern. But this did not work.
Note: I do not have source code to debug i have only files  .aspx files and dll files which are deployed at server.

Comment: There are only two hard problems in computer science: naming things, cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: How do u mean Joel can you please exaggerate

Answer (score 1):

The content to show that the site was "under construction" should have been placed in the app_offline.html file. I don't understand why you even touched the Default.aspx page. Either way the Default page may now be out of synch with its code-behind file. You don't say how much code, if any, is in the code-behind file. So an option for you now would be to create a new Default.aspx and copy/paste and markup and code involved.

Comment: Irish, as i do not have source code, do you mean i just create a new file on root directory with name Default.aspx and copy earlier Default.aspx front end code and paste into new Default.aspx. I would then rename old Default.aspx as Default_Old.aspx, am i thinking right??

Comment: If you are missing source code, you are out of luck. If there is no server-side code, just JavaScript, then yes, you could copy that and the markup into the .ASPX page.

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddler to find out the navigation path. This will help you understand where your request is going.